# R code is not correctly compiling the plot

Tags: r

Here is the question:
[image: Question]

Here is my attempt at solving this question (b) part v):

```
library(ggrepel)
url <- "https://data.incovid19.org/csv/latest/states.csv"
statedf <- read.csv(url)

mystate <- "Telangana"
mystatedf <- subset(statedf, State == mystate)
mystatedf$Date <- as.Date(mystatedf$Date)

Active_cases <- mystatedf$Confirmed - mystatedf$Deceased - mystatedf$Recovered
active <- data.frame(Date = mystatedf$Date, Active_cases)

subset_active <- subset(active, Date >= "2021-07-01" & Date <= "2021-12-31")

head(subset_active,n=30)

ggplot(subset_active, aes(x = Date, y = Active_cases, color = Date)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_viridis_c() +
  labs(title = paste("Active cases for State -", mystate),
       x = "Dates", y = "Cases") +
  theme_minimal()

monthly_deceased_totals <- mystatedf %>%
  filter(Date >= "2020-03-01" & Date <= "2021-12-31") %>%
  filter(!is.na(Deceased)) %>%
  group_by(Month = format(Date, "%B")) %>%
  summarize(Total_Deceased = sum(Deceased, na.rm = TRUE))

month_order <- unique(monthly_deceased_totals$Month)

head(monthly_deceased_totals)

ggplot(monthly_deceased_totals, aes(x = factor(Month, levels = month_order), y = Total_Deceased, fill = Month)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
  labs(title = paste("Monthly Deceased Totals for State -", mystatedf$State[1]),
       x = "Months", y = "Deceased Total") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

```
   total_cases_deceased <- statedf %>%
  group_by(State) %>%
  summarize(Total_Confirmed = sum(Confirmed, na.rm = TRUE),
            Total_Deceased = sum(Deceased, na.rm = TRUE))

ggplot(total_cases_deceased, aes(x = Total_Deceased, y = Total_Confirmed, color = State)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = State), 
                  box.padding = 0.5, 
                  point.padding = 0.1,
                  max.overlaps = 100) +
  labs(title = "Scatter Plot of Confirmed Versus Deceased",
       x = "Deceased Figures", y = "Confirmed Cases") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 8), 
        axis.title = element_text(size = 10)) + 
  scale_x_log10() +
 scale_y_log10()
```

This is the code for the entire 5 parts, the part separated is where the fifth question code is written. Here is the compiled plot.

[image: Image for the plot]

How do I fix this? I am using RMarkdown file on Posit Cloud.

Comment: Try adding `legend.position = 'none'` inside `theme`. You don't need the legend since you have direct labeling, and the legend is taking up more space than your actual plot.